# Using dom-option kills the layout of datatables when using jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I have seen the nice looking table in the [example on datatables.net](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_theme.html).
While trying to implement the jQuery-UI and the related style sheets into my project, the nice layout is gone.
I have stripped down both, the example and my project and figured out that adding the dom option will kill the nice layout.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    // "dom" : 'frtlp',   // uncommenting this line will break the layout      
    "scrollY":        200,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "jQueryUI":       true
} );
```

I have set up an example in jsFiddle. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2jZu/)

Why does the **dom** option kill the layout?
How can I get around this and specify the order of the single components and getting the nice look?

This is what I want to see:
[image]

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to have the same issue. Here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/D2jZu/1/ where you can add or remove options as you like.

```
"dom" : '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>'
```

Read more here http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/9196/jquery-theming-mix-with-sdom-tlfrtip-and-sdom-clfrtip

Comment: Thank you very much Aamir !!!
This works perfect.
Just one more question. I'm using this line now (because I'm added some text labels) `dom : '<"H"Tfr<"MyTableTitle">>t<"F"T<"MyTableSubTitle"><"floatright"lp>>'`.
Is it ok to include a class-definition inside of <"H"> or <"F">?

Comment: Sorry not sure but looks like you can. See this http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sDom